# Hive Getting error on group by column while using case statements and aggregations

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I am working on a query in hive. In that I am using aggregations like sum and case statements and group by clause. I have changed the column names and table names but my logic is same which I was using in my project

```
select 
empname,
empsal, 
emphike,
sum(empsal) as tot_sal,
sum(emphike) as tot_hike,
case when tot_sal > 1000 then exp(tot_hike)
else 0
end as manager
from employee
group by 
empname,
empsal,
emphike
```

For the above query I was getting error as "Expression not in group by key '1000'".
So I have slightly modified the query and tried again My other query is

```
select 
empname,
empsal, 
emphike,
sum(empsal) as tot_sal,
sum(emphike) as tot_hike,
case when sum(empsal) > 1000 then exp(sum(emphike))
else 0
end as manager
from employee
group by 
empname,
empsal,
emphike
```

For above query its putting me  error as "Expression not in group by key 'Manager'". 
When I add manager in the group by its showing invalid alias.
Please help me out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see three issues in your query:

1.) Hive cannot group by a variable you defined in the select block by the name you gave it right away. You will probably need a subquery for that.

2.) Hive tends to show errors when `sum` or `count` operations are not at the end of the query.

3.) Although I do not know what your goal is, I think that your query will not deliver the desired result. If you group by `empsal` there would be no difference between `empsal` and `sum(empsal)` by design. Same goes for `emphike` and `sum(emphike)`.

I think the following query might solve these issues:

```
select
a.empname,
a.tot_sal, 
a.tot_hike,
if(a.tot_sal > 1000, exp(a.tot_hike), 0) as manager
from
(select 
empname,
sum(empsal) as tot_sal,
sum(emphike) as tot_hike,
from employee
group by 
empname
)a
```

The `if` statement is equivalent to your `case` statement, however I find it a bit easier to read.

In this example you wouldn't need to group by after the subquery because the grouping is done in the subquery `a`.